# My class ***UserSynchronizer like CmsUserSynchronizer in abp module cms-kit not exec

Tags: abp

Task HandleEventAsync(EntityUpdatedEto eventData) in my class ***UserSynchronizer don't exec When I create or update user,why?

Comment: Can you share more information about what do you want to use (local or distributed event bus) or what you've tried so far?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: The table CmsUsers  will add a record when I register or create user in cms-kit module ,but my module can't

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your problem has been resolved, but if not, consider looking at the resources below.
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Local-Event-Bus#events-with-past-tense

Code sample from abp repo similar to your purpose:
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/docs/src/Volo.Docs.Domain/Volo/Docs/Documents/FullSearch/Elastic/DocumentChangedEventHandler.cs